# Passing arguments to ngChange event call from inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that accepts an `ng-change` attribute:

```html
<radio-buttons options="optionsList" 
               ng-model="myModel" 
               ng-change="myCallback($event)"></radio-buttons>
```

I've defined a function in my controller, `myCallback`, that looks like this:

```js
$scope.myCallback = function(e) {
    console.log("Callback from controller");   
    console.log(e);
}
```

The following function select exists within my `radioButton` directive. I need to define when the ngChange callback is executed inside my directive in the select function:

```js
function select(scope, val) {
    if (!scope.disabled && scope.selectedValue != val) {
        scope.selectedValue = val;
        scope.model = val;

        scope.callback.call();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is the argument `$event` in `myCallback` is not getting passed along when I execute `myCallback` inside the `select` function of my directive.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/BtrZH/7/ Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/BtrZH/8/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unlike ng*click and ngMouse*, ng-change does not provide an event object.  What exactly do you want the directive to do?  You can bind() to events (like change or keypress) in your directive's link function to be notified of changes/events.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to control when your handler for the ng-change is called, I think the easiest way would be to remove the ng-change completely - you can call the controller function directly from your ng-click callback.

I think this achieves your desired functionality:

http://jsfiddle.net/BtrZH/11/

You can capture the event object from the click if required:

```
ng-click="select(scope, option.value, $event)"
```

Then you can call the controller function when desired:

```
function select(scope, val, $event) {
    if (!scope.disabled && scope.selectedValue != val) {
        scope.selectedValue = val;
        scope.model = val;
        scope.$parent.myCallback($event);
    }
}
```

Comment: unless its an text field and you want the updated text

Comment: I agree with @FlavorScape, had to write a custom handler

Comment: @FlavorScape I agree, but I think this that isn't the use-case for ngChange, since technically it's called after the change is made, so you can't really handle the event after the fact.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the parameter in the callback like so:

```
callback({parametername: value});
```

And you have to match the parameter name with the one declared in the **HTML**

In your case:

```
callback({$event: val})
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work (yes, I've tried it).
First off ng-change="callback({param:value})" is within an angular context so you don't need to escape it with {}. Second, the escaping (outside of ng-change) is done through {{}}, not {}.
Here's an answer that worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18640520/1556338

Answer (score 2):

The following doesn't look good, but would work (it'd create another variable `$event` and pass it via `ng-change`):

```
ng-click="$event = $event" ng-change="myCallback($event)"
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass in values to your controller call it using an object with keys corresponding to the receiver arguments as defined on your template.

e.g.

element

```
<my-element change="myFunction(value, id, event)"></my-element>
```

caller

```
{
   "restrict" : ...,
   "scope" : {
       "change" : "&"
    },
   "controller" : function($scope){
       this.someEventHandler = function($event){

          // called here
          scope.change({
              "value" : "somevalue",
              "id" : "someid",
              "event" : $event
          });

       }
   }
}
```

parent controller receiver

```
$scope.myFunction = function(v, i, e){
   // do stuff
}
```

REF: [Passing arguments to ngChange event call from inside directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710392/passing-arguments-to-ngchange-event-call-from-inside-directive)