# angularjs - pass selected object's other properties on ng-change

Tags: angularjs

How can I get other properties from loaded json in dropdown / ng-options

On ng-change I also like to pass selected object's campaignType.

How would I able to do that?

My View is looking like this

```
  <div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="cCtrl">
        <select ng-model="campaign" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in campaigns" ng-change="search2(c.campaignType)">
            <option value="">-- choose campaign --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller is looking like this

```
  function cCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.campaigns = [{
        "custID": 1,
        "custName": "aaa ",
        "msgID": 3,
        "msgName": "Email Test Msg",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Email Test Campaign",
        "description": "Test Campaign",
        "campaignType": "Email",
        "created": "1374229715",
        "isActive": 1,
        "isDeleted": 0
    }];

 $scope.search2 = function (campaignType) {
        alert(campaignType); // not working
        alert($scope.campaign.campaignType); // not working
        //console.log($scope.campaign.campaignType);

    }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/webtheveloper/Qgmz7/8/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/9/

You are not in an ngRepeat context. ngOptions works totally different.

ngModel on a `<select>` will get the value of the `<option>`, not the whole object. Again, you are not inside an ngRepeat, you don't have access to your objects.

No need to pass the value as parameter, you can get it from `$scope`. As a matter of fact you don't need ngChange either, you can just `$scope.$watch('campaign', ...)`

So

```
$scope.search2 = function () {
    console.log($scope.campaign);
}
```

Comment: sorry this not what I am looking for. I would like to get access to other properties apart from id.

Comment: Then how about searching for it in `$scope.campaigns`? http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/11/

Comment: Error: _ is not defined

Comment: `_` is Lodash (http://lodash.com/) or Underscore, I included it in my fiddle, make sure you don't forget that, or replace `_.find` with some other implementation.

Answer (score 23):

Instead of passing in a property, you can pass the selected object into the function like this

```
<select ng-model="campaign" ng-options="c.name for c in campaigns" ng-change="search2(campaign)">
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vjd6B/)**</kbd>

Comment: Is there any other way? I have already done my coding to receive id in campaign, that is why it was done that way. later on requirement come up to access other properties of object. Now I like to pass object or properties with minimum change. Possible?

Comment: @Developer In your code, what is selected as campaign model is `id` and it is determined by the comprehension expression `c.id as ...`. So I guess there is no other *easy* way since you can't pass anything other than `id` to the function.

Comment: though this not what I was looking for, but plus one for your time.

Comment: @Developer can you change this answer to accepted. Your question "How can I get other properties from loaded json in dropdown / ng-options" is better answered by this one and not the other answer (which I wasted time on!) anyway - my 2 cents

Comment: @Joey This doesn't answer the question. This answer essentially just passes `c.name` and not any other properties from `c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try it this way (Hack we can say),

```
<select ng-model="campaign" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in campaigns" ng-change="search2(campaign,campaigns)">
        <option value="">-- choose campaign --</option>
</select>
```

Basically what this piece of code will do is that it will just pass ng-model along with the whole dropdown list to `ng-change`.
So in search2 Function, you can just search that `ng-model` value into that list and get your desired object.

Fiddle for reference : https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavgavali92/7b7xdyzj/18/

Answer (score 0):

In some cases such as just to display the member value corresponding item selected would not require a call to Controller function. For example if you want to display the campaign type corresponding to selected campaign, it can be written as follow.

```
<select ng-model="campaign" ng-options="c.name for c in campaigns">
```

...

```
<tr><td>Campaign Type:</td><td>{{campaign.campaignType}}</td></tr>
<tr><td>Campaign Description:</td><td>{{campaign.description}}</td></tr>
```